# Gettting the received Http Headers in Angular JS ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, http-headers

I am a newbie for Angular.
I am having the following Angular JS(v.1.7) ui-router

```
.state('helpPage', {
    url: "/help",
    data: {
        roles: []
    },
    views: {
        helpDoc: {
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/help/help.tpl.html',
            controller: 'helpCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

When the User hits this page  I want to retrieve the Headers.
Can I get them in the Controller or in the ui-route's resolve method itself ?

Tried HttpInterceptor but it is not helping out.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is somewhere an http response?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4881836/1443361

Answer (score 0):

Use the `headers` property of the $http `response` object:

```
$http.head(url).then(function(response) {
     var headerGetter = response.headers;
     console.log(headerGetter("headerName"));
});
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - $http.head](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#head)